# Why Java High Level REST Client got introduced in Elastic search?

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-high-level-restclient, elasticsearch-rest-client

There are two Java Rest clients named `Java High Level REST Client` and `Java Low Level REST Client` to integrate with Elastic Search.

**When did `Java High Level REST Client` got introduced in Elastic search and why?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you follow the official documentation you will get to know the differences, how they work and the reason behind adding the `Java High Level REST Client(JHLRC)`.

Coming to the first question when JHLRC was added, as shown in [official doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/master/java-rest-high.html), it was added in `6.0.0-beta1` release.

**Coming to the second question,**

JHLRC works on top of JLLRC and provides additional functionality like marshaling and unmarshalling of requests, which low-level client doesn't provide, apart from that it provides both `sync` and `async` versions of APIs.

More info on the low-level client can be found [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/master/java-rest-low.html) and about high-level client can be found [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/master/java-rest-high.html), which also explains the internals and how they work.