# Partial Document update using Jest Client in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am curious to know which client should I use for elasticSearch using java API. There are multiples clients like Jest, Transport, ElasticSearch clients. Also I have to perform CRUD operations on ES.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [java high level rest client](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/master/java-rest-high.html) as its an official Elasticsearch java client(that supports all documents CRUD operations).

JEST is not official client and not available for latest ES version(not even 7.0 while 7.8 is released so not keeping pace with ES versions).

`Transport` client is used by high level client and is [getting deprecated mention in this official doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/transport-client.html).

Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62421706/4039431) thread for more info on all these clients and how they work internally.